# what is the meaning of words (sites-Files-pages) in plesk statistics

Tags: plesk, visitor-statistic, control-panel

i am using plesk control panel and i am trying to get the number of unique visitor per days 
is plesk-stat  best option?i do not understand the exact meaning of the statistics in plesk-stat report specially  these three words(Files-visits-).
what do  these words stand for ?is there  any better free tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i compared plesk stats and  Google Analytics and i found that google analytics is the best 
tool for all data some one needs about web sites .